# Core Data disappearing after two days

Tags: ios, core-data

Im using core data to persist my data. For the first two days, it stores the data just fine. However, after two days the data goes missing. I have tested this multiple multiple times, with the same results. Am I missing something? Anybody have any suggestions? Below is my CoreDataStack class. Thanks so much!

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CoreDataStack : NSObject

+(instancetype)defaultStack;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;
@end
```

and the implementation file

```
#import "CoreDataStack.h"

@implementation CoreDataStack


@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

+(instancetype)defaultStack{
    static CoreDataStack  *defaultStack;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        defaultStack = [[self alloc]init];
    });

    return defaultStack;
}

- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

// Returns the managed object context for the application.
// If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Wen" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Wen.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
   NSLog(@"%@", url.absoluteString);
    return url;
}

@end
```

insert entry function...ignore that it says breast :) its a baby logging app

```
(void)insertLogEntry {
CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
BreastEntry *entry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"BreastEntry" inManagedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext];

/* Information i left out that is being stored */

[coreDataStack saveContext];

}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code. The problem must lie elsewhere. Are you saving your data? Deleting the app? Clearing out the docs directory?

Comment: are you using multiple threads to do core data stuff? are you actually calling your `saveContext` method?

Comment: @sergio I have 4 view controllers that all use this same coreDataStack... Could that be a problem? In each of the 4 VC's, i have a Save button that calls saveContext.

Comment: @user3784900, you could try grabbing the sqlite database off the app using Xcode's Organizer and then using other tools to see if the data is actually gone.

Comment: Four VC's all using the same stack is not a problem, however you may be initialising the stack each time you `awakeFromNib` or `initWithStyle` each VC, which is unnecessary use of computing power. So my question - when do you call your `defaultStack` method? Once (maybe in app delegate), or for each VC?

Comment: Also SandyChapman's suggestion is worth following... You can open the SQLite db using terminal for the simulator too, by locating the file in your simulator app sandbox. Note Xcode 6 simulator sandbox folder locations are different to Xcode 5 and earlier.

Comment: The consistent crashes after two days makes me think "exhaustion of some resource". What does your app do? Is it creating new NSMO's periodically, as a logging application might? Is an integer counter overflowing? Are you running out of memory? Instruments will tell you this.

Precisely what do you mean by "data goes missing"? The backing store disappears from the filesystem? Or it's there and you can't read it? Or it's there, you can read it, but records have disappeared?

Comment: @andrewbuilder I have added a bit of my code that inserts the data that i record with every 'save' button pressed(see above). This method is able to be called with all the VC's whenever the user presses the 'save' button. So to answer your question, it is being called for each VC it appears

Comment: @SandyChapman Ive been using a version downloaded from the App store to run the tests(which probably is a bad practice), so i am running the tests now over the next couple days with developer version as to check out the sqlite data, per your recommendation. I will report back once i see if the sqlite data is actually being removed.

Comment: if anyone is interested in seeing the whole project/source code, you can find it at https://github.com/srmuhs/Wen_App.git

Comment: @HalMueller I have checked the sqlite data base from the phone after the data starts to disappear. The data is still in the sqlite database, so its not 'deleting' the data. Its just some how removing the data from the view, and also not allowing any data to be input once the 'removing' has begun. Any thoughts on what needs to be done to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did go ahead and find the problem. It had to do with the sort descriptors. I wanted to sort the tableview by section header and then by row. Well, i only had one sort descriptor and it was for the rows. I think this threw off the sorting because it was trying to sort the sections with the row key path, and that somehow made the tableview not load the data after X amount of time. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I take it the app is open this entire time? <del>Have you tried using `saveToPersistentStore:` instead of `save:`?</del> Is your data maintained if you kill the app and relaunch it?

EDIT: Ignore the `saveToPersistentStore:` comment unless you're using RestKit.

Comment: saveToPersistentStore: is not a core data method

Comment: @Sandy Chapman If i kill the app and then reload it, the data comes back...but only for two days. After two days all data is gone. Its always after two days.

Comment: @jrturton, thanks, hadn't realized that's provided as a category by RestKit.